# tsc: Permission denied issue in hosting

Tags: typescript, deployment, backend, tsc, onrender

I'm doing a web project which is developed on angular js for frontend and nodejs with typescript for backend i tried to deploy it on free hosting platform(render.com), then it shows an error while deploying .the error was "sh: 1: tsc: Permission denied" how to resolve this?

I tried the following solutions:-
i) deleted the node module folder and re-installed all packages
ii)installed the tsc and typescript modules with dev-dependency
iii) added tsconfig.json file

i attached the content of tsconfig.json file as image
[tsconfig.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDtii.png)

how to resolve the following issue.

[The error shown in the hosting platform(render.com)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6Jyy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use yarn instead of npm

You don't necessarily need to change your package manager in your development to yarn. Just change the build command to yarn install; yarn build

Write the following:
yarn install; yarn build